# Django NameError name 'request' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

got an error Django NameError name 'request' is not defined.

my `views.py`

```
class ShiftCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('name', 'timein', 'timeout', 'desc')
    model = models.Shift

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.timein = request.POST.get("timein", "")
        self.object.timeout = request.POST.get("timeout", "")
        self.object.save()


        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Please note that this page should contain one question with explanation, not two. Everything like naming, scoring, bounties etc. is tailored to have only one question per question page. Please create a new question for your second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside CBV, request is available from object `self`:

```
self.object.timein = self.request.POST.get("timein", "")
self.object.timeout = self.request.POST.get("timeout", "")
```

Comment: can I add some char to str input ?... if `self.request.POST.get("name", "")` example input `Toyota`, add `camry` so it will `Toyota Camry` on database.

Comment: yes, you can do concatenation with strings

Comment: yes thank you, its worked.